# Prevent iFrame being targeted by JavaScript and having inline styles applied?

Tags: css, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a Chrome extension that inserts an iframe into the page and applies my own styling to it:

```
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.background = 'white';
iframe.style.position = 'fixed';
iframe.style.width = '300px;
iframe.style.height = '50%';
iframe.style.top = '0';
iframe.style.zIndex = '999';
iframe.frameBorder = 'none';
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
```

Most of the time this works fine but there are some sites which target iframes with JavaScript and apply some inline CSS which messes up the Layout. https://exchange.adobe.com/creativecloud.html?zpluginId=12557&mv=product&mv2=accc does this when you resize the browser.

Is there any way around this? I tried setting the inline styles as `!important` but it has on affect.

Comment: Place the iframe inside shadow DOM of a div and reset CSS on `:host` to break inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Solution

You could make use of the css property [`all`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/)
In your case it would look like this:

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.all = 'unset'; // maybe also add `! important`
// ...
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
```

---

### 2. Solution

If you want to ensure that your style attribute does not get changed. You could get it done with a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

```js
const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.all = 'unset'; // maybe also add `! important`
// ...
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);

const observer = new MutationObserver((event) => {
  // check if styles differ from your initial ones
  // fix them if necessary
});

observer.observe(iframe, {
  attributes: true, 
  attributeFilter: ['style'],
  childList: false, 
  characterData: false
});
```

It's kind of brute force. But will work for sure.

Comment: As it's set inline would !important make any difference?

Comment: I think I got your point. All of them are inline (yours and the changed ones). In this case it would make sense to define your styles in a separate style element. Otherwise see 2. solution.

Comment: A different approach would be to add your iframe asynchronously to the dom, so that the sites will not see it on load. I.e. With a small timeout. But I would prefer not to solve it that way. It's kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the sandbox attribute of the iframe? If you set `allow-same-origin` to `false`. Then it will cause the iframe to appear like a cross-origin iframe and block the parent page from accessing it.